# Prevent iOS from leaking memory on mmap (was: mach_vm_map too)

Tags: ios, memory-management, opengl-es, memory-leaks

Context:

- OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS
- Apple's implementation of glBufferData uses mach_vm_map (unavoidable? - it's inside Apple's GL driver) [UPDATE: solved, this was unrelated issue]
- Apple's implementation of CGDataProviderCopyData uses mmap (unavoidable? - it's an Apple system-API)

Observed:

1. create an OpenGL surface, via Apple's GLKViewController / GLKView
2. upload geometry and textures
3. ...
4. discard the VC and V (they dealloc)
5. Apple leaks tens (or hundreds) of megabytes of RAM. If you restart at 1, you get an app crash due to running out of memory :(
6. BONUS:

   1. Apple's Instruments crashes 100% repeatably in "Leaks" mode. Only "Allocations" mode survives Apple's leak

Static Analyzer reports no leaks in the source. [UPDATE: solved, the Static Analyzer in Xcode5 is worse than expected]

Instruments, with Mark Generations, claims that ONLY Apple's two mem-mapping methods listed above are leaking. [UPDATE: coincidence: mach_vm_map was leaking because of a leaked VBO]

As a check ... I over-released the reference (e.g. CFRelease() once too many on the CGDataRef), and it caused the expected crash immediately.

Comment: Are you sure your cleaning up all your OpenGL resources? i.e. deleting all your textures, geometry, etc?

Comment: @JesseRusak automatically yes - in dealloc's of NSObject's. Which lead me to check the dealloc's manually, and the retain/releases, and found what Xcode5 should have caught but didn't (see below). So the OpenGL / mach_vm_map side is solved - but the mmap I still don't understand.

Comment: How about VAOs? Are you deleting them as well. OpenGL has a policy of not releasing memory resources until no container objects contain references to them. This means if you have a GLSL program with a vertex shader and fragment shader attached, if you delete the shaders the only thing that happens is that the IDs used by the shaders are available for re-use by OpenGL, the actual shaders are not freed until the program is deleted or the program's attachments change. The same goes for all OpenGL container objects, VAOs, FBOs, GLSL programs, etc.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `glBufferData (...)` not only supplies data to a VBO in OpenGL, but it also allocates the data store. So the fact that this is the source of a leak is not at all surprising, and would be easily explainable if you neglected to unbind a VBO after deleting it.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the useful points - this stuff isn't well-documented (although with JesseRusak's comment, I found the VBO-related leak for mach_vm_map). It was coincidence that both leaks were maps - but the other map (mmap) is still leaking and isn't part of OpenGL, it's part of CoreGraphics/Quartz, and is released in the same method where its allocated, so I'm stumped what's causing that one.

Answer (score 0):

For the mach_vm_map, it turns out: Xcode5's static-analyzer is broken :(.

A bog-standard memory-leak on a parent NSObject subclass: a missing release - that Xcode4 would have caught.

For the mmap - I still can't find any way to get Apple to release the mmap :(.

Comment: Sounds like you've investigated this thoroughly so I can only suggest logging a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Why don't you ask directly to Apple engineers? In the account you have 2 dst token to use for free

Comment: I'm getting this when you swipe to navigate back just a little bit then let it snap back, causing the view's frame to reset to an unexpected origin and or size.